# functions applied to array elements not firing

Tags: javascript, mobile

I've been stumped on this issue all afternoon; I'm trying to apply Google's Fast Button tutorial to a 'Back' button on my nav: https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons. 
There is a back button for each section, as it's built like so:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="category">
        <a class="back"></a>
            <li class="product">
    </li>
    <li class="category">
    etc...
```

The menu's slide in and out with css3 transitions.
Here's what's driving me nuts; I store all the back buttons, and then send them to an array, and iterate over each one calling the FastButton function.

```
var back = document.getElementsByClassName('back');

back = Array.prototype.slice.call(back);

for (var i = 0; i < back.length; i++) {
            new FastButton(back[i], function(){
                $(back[i]).trigger('click');
            });
        }

('li.back').click(function(){
    doStuff();
});
```

The click fn never fires; I can see the tap-higlight applied and removed, and if I put an alert in, each button fires it. The strange part? Calling a specific index of the array works fine:

```
new FastButton(back[0], function(){
            $(back[0]).trigger('click');
        });
```

For maintainibility's sake I'd rather not do it that way so the nav can be modified down the road without worry. Any insight is much appreciated - I think I've been staring for an error too long and am missing something simple.

Comment: I see lots of issues with this html and js...maybe pasted too fast?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the containing ul's for the nested levels. My bad.

Comment: Set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ that shows the problem.

Comment: I will try; I'm deep in a Java app, so flattening it will take some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are victim of a closure issue. As you are using jQuery, maybe just rewrite your loop:

```
$.each(back,function(i,item){
    new FastButton(item, function(){
        $(item).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting - I feel like that's leading me down the right path, but I'm getting the same result. I will dig in and comment later. Cheers

Comment: @DaveJarvis this part is triggering the click, not responding to it.

Comment: I have corrected my snippet, index and item were in the wrong order.